# Anyone have PECL OAUTH-1.0.0 windows dll?

Tags: pecl

Anyone know where a windows dll for PECL OAUTH-1.0.0?

(0.99.9 is here http://downloads.php.net/pierre/)

Comment: I am also looking for this, did you find one anywhere? I've tried building it but having some issues there.